# Join two queries to get particular table format

Tags: mysql

I have two tables X and Y

```
SELECT ser.entity_type,ser.param_name
FROM X as ser
where
ser.group_name like '%CRVJL%'
and ser.param_name like '%CBV%'
and ser.entity_type like '%SIGNON%'


SELECT reg.entity_type
FROM   REGISTER_TB as reg
where
reg.group_name like '%CRVJL%' and reg.PROV_NAME like'%CBV%' and  reg.PROV_NAME like'%-OD-%' and reg.ENTITY_TYPE like '%SIGNON%'
```

I get some values from table x lets say 4 rows,i have to check if they are present in y or not if not then as -1 and if present then +1

```
  Table should look like this
   entity type  param_name      status
   SIGNON        CBV6815_I-OD-I     1
   SIGNON        CBV7815_I-OD-I     1
   SIGNON        CBV8815_I-OD-I    -1
   SIGNON        CBV9815_I-OD-I     1   

      we have equal columns
      X                 Y
    entity_type       entity_type  
    param-value        prov_name
```

I tried using left join union and right  join but its not giving me output as i want.Can anybody help me?

Comment: what's the source and logic for status field?

Comment: @mynawaz with the first query i am getting some values we need to check if they are present in y table if yes make status 1 if no make it -1,else if it shows null then also its ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this sort of query, you'll have to replace table/field name to match your schema

```
SELECT a.entity_type, a.param_name, IF(b.status IS NULL, -1, 1) AS 'status'
FROM
    X AS a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Y AS b ON a.entity_type=b.entity_type AND a.group_name=b.group_name
WHERE
    a.group_name LIKE '%CRVJL%'
    AND a.param_name LIKE '%CBV%'
    AND a.entity_type LIKE '%SIGNON%'
    AND b.prov_name LIKE '%CBV-OD-%'
```

Comment: @TejasMasurkar glad to help, but there's a mistake, please change `IF(b.status IS NULL, -1, 1)` to `IF(b.entity_type IS NULL, -1, 1)`